# How to format the content received in an email in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4, contactus

I am working on a website in which I want to format content of an email received.

At this moment it is coming up in one line like this with only value showing up.

**Mike abc@gmail.com 9870000000 New York Hello World**

The controller which I have used for the email in Laravel is:

```
Class PostingMessageController extends Controller
{
    public function create() 
    {
        return view('posting');
    }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {

/*
    dd($request->all());

  */   
      $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'number' => 'required',
      'city' => 'required',
      'post' => 'required'
      ]);

       Mail::send('emails.posting-message', [
        'msg'=> $request->name . "\r\n"
        . $request->email . "\r\n"
        . $request->number . "\r\n"
        . $request->city . "\r\n"
        . $request->post . "\r\n"


       ], function($mail) use($request) {

          $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);

           $mail->to('abc@hellworld.com')->subject('Contact Message');
       });

       return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'thank you, your posting info has been sent to our team. we will reach out as soon as we can to provide next steps!');

   } 
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the controller so that everything shows up in different lines like below **with field names at the left and values at the right**. At this moment, I am seeing only values as mentioned above.

```
Name        Mike

Email       abc@gmail.com

Number      9870000000

City        New York

Post        Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to modify you're output of your email, you're probably looking for something you can get into blade and design it and then send it,
here is how i do it

In My Routes : routes/Web.php

```
Route::get('contact-us', 'Main@showContactUs')->name('route_name');
Route::post('contact-us', 'Main@doContactUs')->name('route_name');
```

In My Controller : app/Http/Controllers/Main.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;

class Main extends Controller
{
    public function showContactUs()
    {
        $data = [];
        return View::make('pages.contactUs',$data);
    }
    public function doContactUs(Request $r)
    {
     $fullname = $r->get('fullName');
     $phone    = $r->get('phone');
     $email    = $r->get('email');
     $description = $r->get('message');
     Mail::to('RECEIVER_EMAIL_ADDRESS')->send(new SendMailable($fullname, $phone, $email, $description));
      if (Mail::failures())
      {
        $message1 = " Something Went Wrong.";
      }
      else
      {
        $message2 = " Message Sent Successfully.";
      }
    return redirect()->route('route_name'])->with([
            'warning' => $message1,
            'success' => $message2
        ]);
    }
}
```

then Create this:  app\Mail\SendMailable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $fullname,$phone,$email,$description;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($fullname, $phone, $email,$description)
    {
        $this->fullname = $fullname;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->description = $description;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message. THIS WILL FORMAT YOUR OUTPUT
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('email.layoutOne')->subject('Contact Us Subject');
    }
}
```

Finally in Blade : resources/email/layoutOne.blade.php you can do it like this

```
<div>
    <p>Fullname  : {{ $fullname }}</p>
    <p>Phone No. : {{ $phone }}</p>
    <p>Email Address : {{ $email }}</p>
    <p>Description : {{ $description }}</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Thank you for your Query. We'll get back to you within 24 Hours. </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ViperTechPro The controller code seems to return `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file` not sure what mistake i am doing. Can you have a look ?

Comment: Sure @john i updated my above controller section, i forget to mention class name, also may i take a look of your controller ?

Comment: My controller is posted in the question above but I will be using yours now.

Comment: Do we need to create configure the routes as well for the controller ?

Comment: I am working on it. I will let you know if I have any question.

Comment: No special changes, simply use Post for sending email.

Comment: Ohk thats great then because I was using route before.

Comment: Yes, email.layoutOne is blade view , path will be resouces/views/email/layoutOne.blade.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178880/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail::send('emails.posting-message', [
    'msg'=> "Name\t" . $request->name . "\r\n"
    . "Email\t" . $request->email . "\r\n"
    . "Number\t" . $request->number . "\r\n"
    . "City\t" . $request->city . "\r\n"
    . "Post\t" . $request->post . "\r\n"


   ]
```

Comment: All r still coming in straight line.

Comment: `Field and value pairs` should be in separate lines.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: What is in your template "emails.posting-message" ?

Comment: Just one line, `{{ $msg }}`

Comment: not sure what to say then, \t and \r\n are valid for strings in plain text emails.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the data as an array and format at the view?

```php
$data = array(
    'name'=> $request->name,
    'email'=> $request->email,
    'number'=> $request->number,
    'city'=> $request->city,
    'post'=> $request->post
);

Mail::send('emails.posting-message', $data, function($mail) use($request) {
    $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);
    $mail->to('letsruckify@ruckify.com', 'Name')->subject('Contact Message');
});
```

You can access the variables as $name or $email and implement some table in your blade view like the one in the answer by @ViperTecPro

This is an example of how you can do it... the specific html is up to you.

```
<div>
    <p>Name  : {{ $name }}</p>
    <p>Email Address :    {{ $email }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this code. I am wondering what I should be using inside `email.posting-message`. Because at this moment inside email.posting-message I am using `{{ $msg }}` this.

Comment: just use a table exactly like @ViperTecPro answered... edit: it wasn't a table, but still, thats how you would access

Comment: I think, you didn't get me. emails.posting-message is not a view.

Comment: Check my controller in the question.    
`public function create() 
    {
        return view('posting');
    }`

Comment: Here is `posting` is the view.

Comment: so, whats `emails.posting-message`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail ... add `->view()`so you can format in a view... i don't know if this way of doing things was dropped, this was right on laravel 5.2 https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail and maybe on laravel 5.3...

Comment: Where do you want me to add view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178877/discussion-between-john-and-erubiel).

Comment: when I am copying @ViperTecPro code from the controller, it is telling me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file`